# I am trying to add an element to a js object

Tags: javascript, push, javascript-objects

I try to push key value pairs to an object. the key value pairs have to be added to a certain index which is given by the `e.vatRecord.debit`. This variable is working properly if I log this on console. But in combination it does not work.

```
journalByAccounts = {}; // define an object
  data.entries.forEach(function(e) {
    journalByAccounts[e.vatRecord.debit].push({
      valuta: e.valuta,
      text: e.text,
      debit: e.mainRecord.amount
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Either* you first need to initialize the object `journalByAccounts[e.vatRecord.debit]` to an empty array `[]` because you can't push into `undefined` (expecting that it magically becomes an array):

```
journalByAccounts = {};
data.entries.forEach(function(e) {
    if (!journalByAccounts[e.vatRecord.debit])
        journalByAccounts[e.vatRecord.debit] = [];

    journalByAccounts[e.vatRecord.debit].push({
        valuta: e.valuta,
        text: e.text,
        debit: e.mainRecord.amount
    });
});
```

The `if` is being done to make sure that it still goes right if `e.vatRecord.debit` can contain the same value more than once, creating the array only once for each value.

*Or* if you don't actually want an array, then you should do an assignment:

```
journalByAccounts[e.vatRecord.debit] = {
  valuta: e.valuta,
  text: e.text,
  debit: e.mainRecord.amount
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
journalByAccounts = []; // define an object
```

you must define an empty array, not an obj.